# Can I stop C++Builder inserting USEFORM macros?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe6

I have a C++Builder (XE6) project containing multiple Vcl forms. Only one of them is listed as auto-create on Project>Options>Forms, I create the rest using `new` as and when needed.
The problem is that every so often, C++Builder will insert a load of lines like:

```
USEFORM("TMainForm.cpp", mainForm);
```

into the file with my WinMain method. It will also occasionally shift around the order of these lines.

This leads to the version control history for that file being mostly full of garbage. So is there a way to prevent it inserting the USEFORM macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, **NO**.  You just have to live with it, and delete the macros if you don't want them.

If you are worried about version control issues, see suggestions in this topic:

[IDE generated USEFORM macro calls changing their order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919853/).